# Listview DataTemplateSelector pass parameter to DataTemplate

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I need to send the ObservableCollection as parameter to my custom viewcell, that is invoked through a DataTemplateSelector. Any ideas?

What I want is to remove one Listviewitem when the users clicks a button contained on each item.

Here is the code in the TemplateSelector:

```
private readonly DataTemplate templateOne;
private readonly DataTemplate templateTwo;

public ItemTemplateSelect(ObservableCollection<Item> _items)
{
    templateOne = new DataTemplate(typeof(TemplateOneCell));
    templateTwo = new DataTemplate(typeof(TemplateTwoCell));
}

protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
{
    if (((Item)item).status == -1)
    {
        return templateOne; <---- Here I want to send '_items' as parameter
    }
    else
    {
        return templateTwo;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my viewcell:

```
public class ContactCell : ViewCell
{
    public ContactCell()
    {
        var okButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "OK"
        };
        okButton.Clicked += okButton_Clicked;

        var frame = new Frame
        {
            Padding = 0,
            Margin = 0,
            Content = okButton
        };

        View = frame;
    }

    private async void okButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        -------------> delete current item
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you dont pass item.. you use databinding to attribute values.. can you give me an example of your viewcell?

Comment: Ok I have updated the post with my viewcell example. This all stuff is because I don't know how to handle the okButton_Clicked event from the parent form.

Comment: What i understand is that you have a listview and each item in it contains a delete button.. and when clicked on delete button you want to delete item? Or you want to change datatemplate?

Comment: Yep delete item. But in general handle this click button event from parente side. It is possible?

Comment: Use static variables and im pretty sure that it will work.. create a static function and delete item from observable collection inside.. you call it in your click event..

Comment: Im looking for an example

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Cool..im happy for you;)

Comment: May i ask you another question? What about if i want to navigate? I can't have access to the Navigation method inside the static function...

Comment: Can you explain me the scenario? you click to delete item and then? you want to go to previous page?

Comment: Add a new button. When i click it, the result is open a new form
Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());

Comment: Then maybe you should look for bindable property and forget static values.. I can give an example from my code..

Comment: Ah ok. then you dont need to put button in your listview.. you can use itemtapped event of listview.. it is simpler.

Comment: The thing is that i'm already using the itemtapped event to perform another action. Could you show the bindable example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that if you use static values as you know we cant use Navigation.pushasync function. So i will give you and example how to do without static values. But i dont know if it is the shortest way to do things. What i do is create an instance of your selected object and a function that will open new form in your listview datatemplate and pass datatemplate to your viewcell using bindableproperty. In your viewcell call the function (of datatemplate) in clickevent of your button..

Imagine your item as

```
class myobject
{
...
}
```

and create your listview

```
public class mylistviewTemplate:ListView
{
 public mylistviewTemplate()
 {
   ...
   DataTemplate cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(myobjectcellview));
   cell.SetValue(myobjectcellview.myClickedObject,this);
 }
 public void tapped(myobject item)
{

    Navigation.PushAsync (new myobjectDetailPage (item));
}
...
```

And in your cellview

```
public class myobjectcellview:ViewCell
{
public static readonly BindableProperty myClickedObject = 
BindableProperty.Create<myobjectcellview, mylistviewTemplate>(bip => bip.obj, null);

    public mylistviewTemplate obj
    {
        get {return (mylistviewTemplate)GetValue(myClickedObject);}
        set {SetValue(myClickedObject, value);}
    }
    public myobjectcellview()
    {
      Button btn = new Button();
      btn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
         {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var ctx = (myobject)this.BindingContext;
                obj.tapped(ctx as myobject);    
            }
        };
      this.View = new StackLayout{...};
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this way?
var ctx = (Item)this.BindingContext;

Let me test your code ;)