# xamarin ListView how to get current item or BindingContext in view cell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a `ListView` in Xamarin.Forms. I'm also setting the `ItemTemplate` to my own `DataTemplateSelector` class to chose which `ViewCell` to be used as the `DataTemplate` for each item.

How do I get access to the data for that list view item in my .cs file for each ViewCell? I am trying not to use a xaml file with

```
public class SurveyCell : ViewCell
{

    public SurveyCell()
    {
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label()
        {
            Text = "data from the current item here"
        });

        View = stackLayout;
    }
}
```

I can see an example of how to do it with a .xaml file here with binding: 
https://github.com/nishanil/Xamarin.Forms-Samples/blob/master/DataTemplateSelector/DataTemplateSelector/DataTemplateSelector/CustomCells/OutgoingViewCell.xaml

but I am only using .cs without a matching .xaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better practice way to do this, but overriding `OnBindingContextChanged` and building the `ViewCell` in there seems to work. `BindingContext` is null in the constructor, but is filled out in `OnBindingContextChaanged`

```
public class NewsCell : ViewCell
{
    public NewsCell()
    {
        //null here
        NewsItem data = (NewsItem)BindingContext;
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        // works here
        NewsItem data = (NewsItem)BindingContext;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewCell` will take in the `BindingContext` of a single item in your `ListView.ItemSource` collection.

So you can bind your `Label.Text` to the item's value like so:

Example Survey model:

```
public class Survey {
    public SurveyName { get; set; }
}
```

Example SurveyCell:

```
public class SurveyCell : ViewCell {

    public SurveyCell() {

        Label label = new Label();

        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Survey.SurveyName));

        //label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SurveyName"); //This is the same as above but without having to use a "magic string", this way works without C# 6 though

        View = new StackLayout {
            Children = { label }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object in your listview with:

```
var ctx = (myobject)this.BindingContext; //use it in the viewcell
```

If not you can look at this post
[Listview DataTemplateSelector pass parameter to DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650318/listview-datatemplateselector-pass-parameter-to-datatemplate?noredirect=1#comment68577535_40650318)

Comment: I tried this before posting the question(and should have included that in my original question, sorry) however my BindingContext is always null

Comment: Its true that when you load your list bindingcontext is null. In the post we get the item when clicked. What you can do is to set data before you pass your list to viewcell and use the method of hvaughan3